# Can browsers produce different resolutions of an image?

Tags: javascript, css, image-processing

Given an image, say as a jpeg file, is there a way to display it on a web page in different resolutions?

Note that unlike similarly worded questions, I'm *not* talking about changing the size of the image on the page.

And no, I'm *not* asking for CSI software that magically adds detail to low resolution images.

What I want is something like this:

[image: Three identically sized copies of Mona Lisa, in high, medium, and low resolution]

where the first image is the original high resolution file (205×304), and the others are the same file displayed with medium (82×122) and low (41×61) resolution.

Is there CSS or javascript that can do this?

(CSS `filter: blur()` has a similar effect, but is not what I want (e.g. no jaggies).)

Comment: For as for as I know you need to degrade the image with JS. CSS4 will have the `image-resolution` attribute (probably...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image manipulation is (often) done by creating/loading a `<canvas>`, drawing the image on the `<canvas>` and do some required modifications. In this case, simply load the image in the `<canvas>` an redraw it with a different size on the canvas `2d context`.

The **snippet** below shows two flavours: **with** `degradeImage()` and **without** `degradeImageOnParent()` pre-existing `<canvas>` in the document.

**STRANGELY** the snippet shows only one image, while outside Stackoverflow it shows four: original and 3 degraded images. Must be a document loading issue, working on this....

**Resolved** disabled `docInit`...

```js
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',docInit);

//function docInit() {
    document.getElementById('source').onload = function () { 
        degradeImage(0.75, this, document.getElementById("cvs1"));
        degradeImage(0.50, this, document.getElementById("cvs2"));

        // Add canvas on-the-fly
        degradeImageOnParent(document.getElementById('parent'),0.25,this,'cvs3');
    };
//};

function degradeImage(scale,img,cvs) {
    if (!cvs) { // if not passed, create canvas on-the-fly
        cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    }
    var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

    cvs.width  = img.width  * scale; // assign scaled size
    cvs.height = img.height * scale;

    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true; // default value, here for reference only
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height); // fill the canvas
    
    return cvs; // Useful when created inside function
}

function degradeImageOnParent(parent,scale,img,cvsID) {
    var cvs = degradeImage(scale,img);
    if (cvsID) cvs.id = cvsID; // [optional ID]
    parent.appendChild(cvs);
}
```

```css
.wrapper   { width: 100% }
canvas,img { width:  24% } /* original is 400x600 */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="parent">
    <img id="source" src="https://i.postimg.cc/76JT0MBh/Mona-Lisa-400.jpg">
    <canvas id="cvs1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cvs2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: My version is using promises because contrarily to yours, it does handle waiting for the source image to load. Otherwise, your answer is just a copy of mine with nothing added, so I'm not sure what input you are expecting from my part...  And I'm not sure what you mean with your 15% thing, 15% of what do you think that should be?

Comment: 15% of the current parent width, whatever that may be....

Comment: And where does this comes from? Of course you can set the images in my answer to this size, you just need to set the parent's width.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do it quite simply with a <canvas> element, just set it `width` and `height` attributes to the target ones, and draw your image on it. Then you just have to resize these canvases with CSS if you wish:

```js
function downscale( img, width, height ) {
  const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    if( img.naturalWidth ) { // if already loaded
      draw();
    }
    else {
      img.addEventListener( 'load', draw, { once: true } );
      img.addEventListener( 'error', reject, { once: true } );
    }
    
    function draw() {
      ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, width, height );
      resolve( canvas );
    }
  } );
}

const img = document.querySelector( 'img' );
// original image size: 158 * 240
Promise.all( [
  downscale( img, 79, 120 ),
  downscale( img, 40, 60 )
] ).then( (canvases) =>
  document.querySelector( '.img-container' )
    .append( ...canvases )
)
.catch( console.error );
```

```css
img, canvas { height: 240px }
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg"></div>
```

To do it with CSS only sounds theoretically possible, e.g by upscaling using `width` and `height` properties and then downscaling using transforms, but it seems implementations will just batch all the operations rather than applying one by one and thus both operations will just revert each other instead.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, if you can spare the time, could you please comment on my answer and discus possible pittfalls compared to your answer with 'promises'. I do understand why using 'promises' would be the preferred way of coding, esp. with much online I/O (delays) going on. BTW, your version fails when the CSS `img,canvas {...}` is used with different values (e.g. `img, canvas { width: 15% }` fails, tried this outside SO).